# Q: Google Sheets Script "InternalError: Cannot convert to (class)"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I wrote a Google Script for my spreadsheet (a lot of copy/paste online) that is intended to transfer a row of data from one sheet to another sheet if a date matches to the current date (it runs once per day).  The code works, with one exception of row 24 where I get an error of "Cannot conver XXX to (class)" with XXX representing the data in that row.  It seems it may be something with how I'm defining the variable source_range but I just can't get it to work!  Any help is much appreciated.  The goal is that within the for loop it copies the "current" row of data based on variable i.  If I change the source_range parameters to something static (like row 3, for example) it works perfectly.... but of course then it only pastes row 3 every time which is not what I desire.  Any suggestions help!

```
    function AutomationEnroll() {
      try{

    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("XXXHIDDENXXX");
    var source_sheet = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheets()  [2]);
    var target_sheet = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheets()[3]);


    var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
    var numRows = source_sheet.getLastRow()-1;   // Number of rows to process
    var dataRange = source_sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, source_sheet.getLastColumn());
    // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
    var data = dataRange.getValues();

    for (i in data) {
      var row = data[i];
      //Logger.log(sheetDate);
      var TodayDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),'GMT','EEE, d MMM yyyy')
      var SurgeryDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(row[1]),'GMT', 'EEE, d MMM yyyy')

      if (TodayDate == SurgeryDate){

      //I now need it to copy row[i] in sheet[2] over to the last_row in sheet[3]  ;
        var source_range = source_sheet.getRange(data[i], 1, 1, 12)    //error converting to (class)                                     
        var last_row = target_sheet.getLastRow();
        target_sheet.insertRowAfter(last_row);
        var target_range = target_sheet.getRange("A"+(last_row+1)+":L"+(last_row+1));
        source_range.copyTo(target_range);

       }    
     }
   }catch(err){
     Logger.log(err.lineNumber + ' - ' + err);
   }
}`
```

Comment: What exactly is the error returned (i think the typical error is "Cannot convert NaN to Class", which I'm assuming is a [Range class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range))? Are there logs you can share?